# How do you write "SELECT ... WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)" in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have trouble following the reverse related relationship in a Django query:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

"Get the reporters who wrote an article about coronavirus":

```sql
SELECT * FROM myapp_reporter
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT reporter_id FROM myapp_article WHERE title ILIKE '%coronavirus%'
    )
```

How do I write this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Reporter.objects.filter(article__title__icontains='coronavirus')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) on queries that span relationships explains this in more detail, including how to determine the name of the query parameter to use.

Comment: However, I see that to achieve the same result with `SELECT count(*)` in said query, I need to use `.distinct().count()`. Apparently the query resulting from Django is more similar to `SELECT ... FROM myapp_reporter r INNER JOIN myapp_article a ON a.reporter_id=r.id WHERE ...`. I wonder, is it as efficient as the `WHERE id IN (SELECT...)` one?

Comment: I suspect it probably isn't quite as efficient - but it's what is possible using the ORM.